# How to append text to the output file redirected by perl command

Tags: bash, shell, redirect

The command

```
perl myperlscript.pl > output.txt 2>&1
```

is redirecting output to the file. But it is overriding the file every time. How to append the text to the end of existing file?

Comment: Perhaps `perl myperlscript.pl >> output.txt 2>&1`?

Comment: This is well documented in the bash man page. For an online resource: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append, you can use `>>` instead of `>`.

In your case, the new command will be:

```
perl myperlscript.pl >> output.txt 2>&1
```

`2>&1` is redirecting the stderr to stdout (the output of stderr will also be saved in `output.txt`), so you don't need `>>` there.